# Is there a way to stop web-push notification on a Google chrome on one device if it is already received on a Google chrome on another device?

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have implemented push notifications using web-push that works on Google chrome.

Is there a way to stop web-push notification on a Google chrome on one device if it is already received on a Google chrome on another device?

Answer (score 0):

This would require you to access something in a distributed store before pushing the notification to the end user. For example, your logic could be something similar to:

```
// Only one client can get a lock at a time
var lock = await api.getPushNotificationDistributedLock(); 

// Get the status
var pushNotificationStatus = await api.getPushNotificationStatus();

// Send the notification if it hasn't already been sent
if(pushNotificationStatus === "pending") {
    // Push notification to user
    await api.setPushNotificationStatus("completed");
}

// Release the lock
lock.release();
```

The first client to get the lock will see the status as `pending` and successfully send the push notification. After it updates the status to `completed`, every subsequent client will see the status as completed and carry on.